# Grafana expression suddently says 2 items dropped from union(s)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

After upgrading from Grafana 10.1 to 10.2, some panels stopped working.
More specifically, the expression `$A + $B * -1` stopped working and gave a warning:

```
2 items dropped from union(s): ...
```

[image]
Any idea why?

I am no promql ninja, is there a way to get those metrics in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it stopped working, and if I had to guess, I'd say it shouldn't be working at all. Reasoning: your metrics have different labelsets.

If all you need is to get result of subtraction of metric with "positive" label from "negative" one, you can use following promql query:

```
badin42_energy_power{direction="negative"} - ignoring(direction) badin42_energy_power{direction="positive"}
```

Here we are using [`ignoring` keyword](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching-keywords), to make Prometheus match two metrics based on all labels except for the `direction`.

Comment: Thank you for your very instructive answer. Your query does indeed produce the dataset I was looking for.